# The convolution is positive in a set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f , g$ be two non-negative functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
m(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) > 0\}) , m(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : g(x) > 0\}) > 0\mbox{.}
$$
Show that exists a measurable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, with $m(A) > 0$, such that $f*g > 0$ on $A$. Begining, I though $A$ could have the form of
$$
A_1 = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) > 0\} \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R} : g(x) > 0\}
$$
or
$$
A_2 = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) g(x) > 0\}
$$
but $A_1$ or $A_2$ can have measure zero; in fact, take $f = {\chi}_{(0 , 1)}$ and $g = {\chi}_{(- 1 , 0)}$. Can you help me to find $A$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes I forgot write this in the question thank you I change the enunciate

Comment: Look at translations of one of the functions and define a parameter dependent family of $A$s

Comment: But if $f(x) > 0$, can happen $f(x - y) = 0$.

Comment: That's not a problem. Look at the counter example to your approach that you gave and see what happens when you translate one of your functions.

Comment: Look at $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} (f\ast g)(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: @Daniel that's clever. I'm not sure if OP has Tonelli yet though.

Comment: What is OP? and what can I do with this integral?

Comment: Do you have a theorem for interchanging integrals?

Comment: Tonelli and Fubini of course.

Comment: Oh goodie. Use Tonelli on the integral Daniel gave. Note that convolution is given by an integral so you'll end up changing the order.

Comment: In this case i would use Tonelli. But I don't obtain anything later using Tonelli theorem on double integral.